# Stream, Grand Central Dispatch and synchronization problems

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, ios10

I have problem with stream and GCD.

In AppDelegate I have connection instance in 
`let queue =  DispatchQueue("Connection")`
 In connection class I want to get data, print them and send do static object in appdelegate.
My problem is that when i used

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{print("") code}
```

in connection class, it doesn't work. 
The same:

```
Dispatch.global().async{print("") code}
```

Here is my sample app in hyperlink. [My sample app](http://www.filedropper.com/gcdstreamtesteng)

ps. Sorry for this hosting. Some one know some good server for file sharing?

Comment: "It doesn't work" ... What do you expect us to figure out from that?

Comment: Some advice, help, why this is happening.
Perhaps a good example of the GCD.
Anything that will help me.
This is the third day I struggle with this one problem.

Comment: "why this is happening" What's "this"?

Comment: "this one problem." you haven't told us what the problem is